# How can I generate a list of possible 'words' when all I know is the number of letters of each word in Python?

Tags: python

I know this is probably a dumb question and I am missing something really simple, but I can't for the life of me figure out where I am going wrong...  I am ultimately trying to generate a list of all possible letter combinations with a string of a given length.  I know some of these letter combinations wont be pronounceable, but I am going to call them 'words' nonetheless for simplicity.  For example, if I know my string is one letter long, I want to generate a list of letters, "A" though "Z", 26 elements long.  If I know my string is two letters long, I will need a list of "words" from "AA" to "ZZ", 676 elements long.  The rub comes where I do not know the number of letters ahead of time.

If I know my 'word' will only be one letter, then I can do this:

```
letters = ["A", "B", "C", ... "X", "Y", "Z"]
words = []
for x in range(26):
    words.append(letters[x])
print(words)
```

If I know my 'word' will be two letters long, I can do this:

```
letters = ["A", "B", "C", ... "X", "Y", "Z"]
words = []
for x in range(26):
    for y in range(26):
        words.append(letters[x] + letters[y])
print(words)
```

What I can't for the life of me figure out is how to do this when I don't know ahead of time how many letters my word will have.  I basically want a formula where I give it the number of letters, and it gives me a list of all the possible words, that number of letters long.  Something to the effect of:

```
def possible_words(word_length):
    list_of_words = []
    number_of_words = 26 ** word_length
    for x in range(number_of_words):
        '''generate the new word here'''
        list_of_words.append(new_word)
    return list_of_words
```

Where am I going wrong?  What am I missing?  I feel like I am so close, I know this has to be a simple problem, but I have been racking my brain for a few hours now and can't figure it out.  I feel like the solution lies in something involving recursion?  And I think I maybe can't get the numbers to line up with the words because of a combination of zero-indexing and the fact that a 'zero letter' doesn't exist?  I don't know, the more I think the more confused I get...  Please help!  Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Thanks to those who responded and specifically to njp and Thierry Lathuille who directed me towards itertools.product!  The solutions was even more pythonic than I could have hoped for!  Below is the code I ended up using, in case anyone else comes across the same issue:

```
import itertools

alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
word_length = 2    # The 2 is just for testing, actual value will be determined programatically...
letter_tuples = itertools.product(alphabet, repeat=word_length)
words = ["".join(letter_tuple) for letter_tuple in letter_tuples]
print(words)
```

Comment: See itertools.product

Comment: Thank you Thierry, I edited my question with my revised code that does what I need using itertools.product, and gave you a shoutout!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get what you want using `itertools.product`, specifically:

```
import itertools as it

list(it.product(letters, repeat=3))
```

```
 ('A', 'A', 'B'),
 ('A', 'A', 'C'),
 ('A', 'A', 'D'),
 ('A', 'A', 'E'),
 ('A', 'A', 'F'),
 ...
```

`it.product` works exactly as nested for-loops.

Comment: If anyone is interested, there's some sample code for how `itertools.product` could be implemented in the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product

Comment: Thank you njp!  This did it for me!  Your answer is marked as an answer and upvoted, and I edited my question with the code I wrote implementing your solution for my problem!  Thanks again!

Comment: Thank you Oli, I appreciate the examples the docs give.  I ended up putting the entire output into a list, because I'm not so much worried about the memory usage for my use case, but someone needed every bit of efficiency could and should definitely take advantage of the generator aspect of it!

Answer (score 0):

this is a standard [permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#k-permutations_of_n) problem.

what you want is:
[itertools.permutations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations)

Comment: Permutations unfortunately wasn't the answer, but product was!  Thank you for sending me towards itertools!

Answer (score 0):

I created a bit of code. I think this is what you mean. You change the variable on how many times each letter is shown. I hope this helps.

```
word_length = 1
list_of_words = []
letters = ["A", "B", "C",'D','E', 'F','G','H','I',"J",'K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W',"X", "Y", "Z"]
letter_on = 0
count = 0
for x in range(word_length*len(letters)):
  if letter_on != 27:
    if count != word_length:
      list_of_words.append(letters[letter_on])
      count+=1
    else:
      count=0
      letter_on+=1
  else:
    break

print(list_of_words)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this code does not do what I need.  When I ran it, it gave me a list of the first 13 letters, when based on a default of 1 as a word length I would have expected it to give me all 26 letters of the alphabet as a list.  I changed the word length to 2, but got even more bizarre results.  The list contained 35 elements total, and had each letter twice in alphabetical order up until the 35th letter, which it obviously only had one of.